# GOOGLE SHEETS — Display file size from large list of Image URLs

Tags: google-sheets

I have a long list of image URLs in Google Sheets that takes a long, long time to populate in each cell. I was hoping to shorten the process by simply displaying the URL's relevant files sizes in the column next to the links to then filter by the greater sized images.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

——

I found a similar script on the link below, but that was to display file sizes relating to a Google drive:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/58260211/how-can-i-get-google-drive-file-sizes-in-a-gsheet?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the urls are in `A1:A100`, you can output the sizes in bytes to `B1:B100` with:

```js
function getSizes() {
  const input = 'A1:A100';
  const output = 'B1:B100';
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const urls = sheet.getRange(input).getValues();
  const sizes = urls.map(row => [UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[0]).getBlob().length]);
  sheet.getRange(output).setValues(sizes);
}
```

Comment: Ran it, still noting showing in column B.